# iOS - CoreBluetooth didDiscoverPeripheral not being called

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have made a very simple iOS app in Xcode 6 to try out CoreBluetooth and communicate to my Polar H6 heart rate monitor. For some reason the didDiscoverPeripheral method is not being called.

I have found the following similar questions on StackOverflow but thy are either a bit different or do not really answer it for me:

- [corebluetooth-diddiscoverperipheral-not-being-called-in-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039103/corebluetooth-diddiscoverperipheral-not-being-called-in-swift)
- [not-working-call-to-centralmanager-diddiscoverperipheral-advertisementdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826693/not-working-call-to-centralmanager-diddiscoverperipheral-advertisementdata-rs)
- [diddiscoverperipheral-delegate-method-is-not-called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337604/diddiscoverperipheral-delegate-method-is-not-called)

My code in viewDidLoad:

```
NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:HRM_HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID]];
CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:nil];
self.centralManager = centralManager;
```

Method `centralManagerDidUpdateState` is being called and it tells me state is equal to `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn`.
The `didDiscoverPeripheral` method is never called, not even when I pass `nil` into the `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` method.

Within the app store I have downloaded d an app called LightBlue. Its a very simple app to test any device which uses Bluetooth 4.0 LowEnergy. It scans for peripherals and shows detailed info about the devices and its services. 
The LightBlue app does see my HeartRate monitor, while my own little app does not..

Does anybody have any tips or clues how to go forward with this?

(I am using Xcode 6 and and iPhone 6 with iOS 8)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 8 Core Bluetooth not discovering peripherals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586527/ios-8-core-bluetooth-not-discovering-peripherals)

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks! it is indeed the same question (a shame i did not find it myself) and it gave me the solution!

Comment: Please check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167804/why-use-corebluetooth-connectperipheral-did-not-call-delegate-methods-in-ios8/31961410#31961410

Answer (score 1):

I am using Swift, and it looks like the Bluetooth queue needs to be using the main queue

```
myCentralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
```

Here it is in objective C

```
myCentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] 
    initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Comment: @discussion     The initialization call. The events of the peripheral role will be dispatched on the provided queue.
 * If <i>nil</i>, the main queue will be used.